# Button is not stretched when the underlying frame it is in nested layouts

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this MRE in which I have a main frame with two frames as children and each of these contains a basic widget. The first frame contains a label that purposely takes up a lot of space in width. The second frame, to which I have set a red background, contains a button that I would like to have fully stretched to the width of the frame in which it is contained.

```
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")

style = ttk.Style()

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)
frame = ttk.Frame(mainframe)
label = ttk.Label(frame, text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet")
frame2 = ttk.Frame(mainframe, style="debug.TFrame")
button2 = ttk.Button(frame2, text="Button22222")

mainframe.grid()
frame.grid()
label.grid()
frame2.grid(sticky="we")
button2.grid(sticky="we")

# frame2.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

style.configure("debug.TFrame", background="red")

root.mainloop()
```

So, I have some questions:

1. Why the button even though I set the sticky option of the column to `we` does not stretch if the red background of the frame shows how the frame is fully stretched to the width of the label?
2. Why does the button lose its padding?
3. I actually found a solution (which is commented at the end) but I do not understand why it works. I usually use `columnconfigure` when I need to decide how the columns should resize when extra space becomes available.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: `columnconfigure()` is on how available space is *allocated* to a column and `sticky()` is on how the *allocated space* is used.  If `columnconfigure()` is not executed, then ask yourself *how many space will be allocated for that column*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the button even though I set the sticky option of the column to we does not stretch if the red background of the frame shows how the frame is fully stretched to the width of the label?

This is because columns by default don't expand to fill extra space in the parent. Instead, they shrink (or grow) to fit there children. Any extra space in the window goes unused.

If you want the first column in a frame to expand to fill the frame, you must give it a non-zero `weight` this will instruct `grid` to allocate any unused space to that column.

So, in your case you must call `grid_columnconfigure` three times: one for the root window, one for `mainframe`, and one for `frame2`.

```
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

You'll also want to use the `sticky` attribute on all of those widgets so that the frames will grow to fit the space allocated within the column.

As a rule of thumb when using `grid`, you should always give at least one row and one column a non-zero weight.